# Why the BSC block gas limit change and what's the logic behind it?

Tags: gas-limit, binance-smart-chain

The bsc block gas limit is always very close to 120,000,000. But it can be 119,529,427 or 119,996,337 for some blocks. It seems to stay between 118M and 120M

Why does it change and what's the logic behind this ?

**Block 22,966,086 :**

[image]

**Block 22,966,087:**

[image]

EDIT : now the block gas limit is 140,000,000 or under, but the logic seems to be the same.

Comment: I'm not sure about BSC, but on Ethereum the maximum gas is also variable. When the blocks start to get too full, the maximum gas increases along with the base rate value for the gas. I think the idea is to increase the gas cap to accommodate more transactions, but at the same time increase the gas value, thus decreasing the number of transactions. It is a quest toward balance.

Comment: I checked and the eth block gas limit stay constant at 30M, only the base fee change to control the amount of txs in the block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been reviewing the source code for the bnb node (erigon version). I've discovered that it follows the same mechanism as Ethereum or Polygon in which in each block, the producer could vary the gas limit by (parent_block_gas_limit / 1024). In Ethereum & Polygon seemed to be introduced in the London fork (not adopted by BNB) but in BNB has been introduced without this fork. The source code of this mechanism is [here](https://github.com/bnb-chain/erigon/blob/abb5c9a5c4bd701de5d7fb4fb9b6b0f8f7c167c8/core/block_validator.go#L26).

Nodes have in their configuration a parameter called [TargetGasLimit](https://github.com/bnb-chain/erigon/blob/abb5c9a5c4bd701de5d7fb4fb9b6b0f8f7c167c8/eth/stagedsync/stage_mining_create_block.go#L211) this would make the nodes propose a block with this TargetGasLimit or the closest in the available range (due to the parent_block_gas_limit / 1024 restriction).

One posible answer is that a BNB node hasn't changed their TargetGasLimit param from 120M to 140M so when this node gets a block mined the produced block gas limit would slighty decrease a bit.